# How do declare global variable in PHP class

Tags: php, oop, global-variables, private

```
class Auth extends Controller {

    function __constructor(){
        private $pass;
    }
    function Auth()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }
    function index(){
            ..........
    }
    function loging(){
                $this->pass = "Hello World";
    }
    function test(){
                 var_dump($this->pass); // this is on the  line 114
    }
}
```

When I access the test function I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRIVATE in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/application/controllers/auth.php on
>   line 6

instead of the string "Hello World". I wonder why ? Can anyone help me with this ? Thx in advance

Comment: declare the class properties (`private $pass;`) beside the methods not inside them. Also `__constructor()` should be `__construct()`.

Comment: the idea is : How can I update the private variable in a function and access the updated value in another function , of course in the same class

Comment: Then @Rob's answer looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you're not trying to create a "global variable" (as your title suggests), but a private member variable.

In order to do that you need to declare the private member variable outside of the constructor:

```
class Auth extends Controller {

    private $pass;

    function __construct(){
    }

    function auth()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('cookie');
        $this->load->library('email');
    }
    function index(){
            ..........
    }
    function loging(){
        $this->pass = "Hello World";
    }
    function test(){
        echo $this->pass;
    }
}
```

Also:

- Correct the name of your constructor
- Chose a naming convention (e.g. lowercase first character of function names) and stick to it.

As a trivial answer / example of what you are asking.  Try this:

```
<?php

    class Auth {

        private $pass;

        function __construct(){
        }

        function loging(){
            $this->pass = "Hello World";
        }
        function test(){
            echo $this->pass;
        }
    }

    $oAuth = new Auth();
    $oAuth->loging();
    $oAuth->test();

?>
```

It outputs:

```
C:\>php test.php
Hello World
```

Comment: now im getting this error :  Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/clients/client1/web15/web/application/controllers/auth.php on line 114

Comment: I changed its value to "Hello World". I don't know , why im getting this error

Comment: Now you're getting an error in a completely different bit of code in a completely different area of your application.  That kind of sounds like you need to debug what you have and them raise a new SO question if you can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
class Example extends CI_Controller
{

  public $variable = "I am Global";

  public function test()
  {
    echo $this->variable; // I am Global
  }

  public function demo()
  {
    echo $this->variable; // I am Global
  }

}
```

Or in your case make the variable `$pass` `public` instead of `private`

```
public $pass;//<==make change here
```

And use the variable using `$this`

Comment: but what does it happen when I modified $this->variable in test function and i want to print it the modified variable in the function demo ?

Comment: if you modify the global variable in any function than its scope will only remain in that controller and when you use it in another controller than it will show its global value.

Comment: It's not a global - it's a public member variable.  It may seem I'm being pedantic but the distinction is very important if you are to understand object oriented development.

Comment: the ideea is : I want to declare a public or private variable in the class. After that , in a public function I assigned to that variable a random value and i want to access in the same class but in another function that random value from the public or private variable. how can I do that ?

Comment: or How can I update the private variable in a function and access the updated value in another function , of course in the same class

Comment: if you want to navigate the variable between two function in same class than you can call the another function in with `this` and pass the value of variable in that.